# Problems to extract links with webscraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to extract the links of the toys listed in this webpage:
https://cebra.com.ar/category/73/Juego-de-Construccion.html

I have an entire procedure (I don´t copye here because it´s very long and complicated), in which in some part I have the following code that doesn´t work:

```
 Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByTagName("a").href
```

Any idea to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that "_the following code doesn't work_" is not a proper problem definition. You should describe the exact error you get when executing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection and indeed you would need to index into it to get a particular element.

However, you don't want all `a` tags. That is inefficient and you would need an additional test to limit to those of interest. You want specifically the links for products so use an [attribute = value css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get those:

```
Dim links As Object, i As Long
Set links = html.querySelectorAll("[href^=product]")

For i = 0 to links.Length - 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(erow + i, 1) = links.item(i).href
Next
```

This:

```
[href^=product]
```

looks for `href` attributes whose value starts with, ^,  `product`.

If you look at the page html you can see each of your target links begins with that substring

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function `getElementsByTagName()` of the object `HTMLDocument` returns a list, but you're trying to access the property `.href` of one object as if it was a single object.

You should replace this:

```
Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByTagName("a").href
```

with this

```
Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByTagName("a")[yourIndex].href
```

... where `yourIndex` is a number representing the index of your list (`0`, `1`,... `n`).

Of course you'll have to find the correct rule to get the right `a` element at the right place, as just getting all the elements of the document with tag `a` retrieves 278 elements in your page (including all the page headers, footers and other things I don't really think you need):

[image]